# qiskit from Anaconda spyder: Missing module error

Tags: qiskit

I'm a newcomer to qiskit, when I tried to import qiskit, it followed a **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit._accelerate'**. I've tried creating a new virtual environment and re-install qiskit, but the same error popped out.

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit._accelerate']
[image: Using "pip list" to check if qiskit is downloaded.]

Also here comes another error after commenting out the "qiskit._accelerate" in "**init**" :
[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retworkx.retworkx']

It seems that there are some missing modules, but how can I figure it out? Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: did you try to reinstall qiskit, it should solve the problem, it also happened to me before with `tox -elint` to pr branch, but not effect too much.

Comment: yes I've tried it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current solution you can try:

- `pip install spyder-kernels` if using pip/virtualenv
- `pip3 install qiskit` or `pip install qiskit`
- make sure "conda activate ur_env_name"

related wiki: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

Comment: It doesn't work, thanks for your effort tho.

Comment: @holahaha can you open a new conda env, and install required packages like `pip install qiskit` and `pip install spyder-kernels` and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @holahaha did you tried reinstall spyder

Comment: because I search related issue on spyder github, it got 253 same cases with import problem, I tried myself, I solve it with pip install spyder-kernel

Comment: I think you can troubleshoot this on spyder github by posting issue will much faster. @holahaha

Comment: ok, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problems have been solved.

The problems lie in the version of python, the version I used in the aforementioned case was 3.9.12, whereas it works as I create a new env with python 3.8.13 or 3.8.8.

It's probably related to compatibility.

@poig Thanks for your help, btw.